# In aosp can not lunch emulator with error emulator: WARNING: encryption is off libGL error: unable to load driver: vmwgfx_dri.so

Tags: android, emulation, vmware, android-source

**emulator: WARNING: encryption is off

libGL error: unable to load driver: vmwgfx_dri.so

libGL error: driver pointer missing

libGL error: failed to load driver: vmwgfx

libGL error: unable to load driver: swrast_dri.so

libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast

X Error of failed request:  BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation)

Major opcode of failed request:  155 (GLX)

Minor opcode of failed request:  24 (X_GLXCreateNewContext)

Value in failed request:  0x0

Serial number of failed request:  33

Current serial number in output stream:  34**

Comment: I build aosp in ubuntu 16.04 in Vmware ,Thanks!